# c++ call to base class method slices object

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overloading, object-slicing

I have something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class X;

class A {
public:
  virtual void bar(X &x);
};

class B : public A {
public:
};

class X {
public:
  void foo(A &a) { std::cout << "foo A" << std::endl; }
  void foo(B &b) { std::cout << "foo B" << std::endl; }
};

void A::bar(X &x) { x.foo(*this); }

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  X x;
  B b;
  b.bar(x);
  return 0;
}
```

Compile it and execute it, you'll have:

```
# ./a.out
foo A
#
```

I believe this is because object is sliced when cast to A. How can I avoid this so I get

```
foo B
```

without implementing the method in B or using some weirdness like the [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No slicing is going on here, because you carefully pass objects by reference; slicing requires manipulating the object by value.

The effect is due to *overload resolution*, which is done statically (i.e. at compile time). When C++ compiles this member function

```
void A::bar(X &x) {
    x.foo(*this);
}
```

it needs to decide, at compile time, which of the two overloads to pick. The decision is simple: the compiler knows that `*this` is of type `A`, so it calls `void foo(A &a)` function.

You cannot get it to work without implementing the same method in `B`<sup>*</sup>, using templates, or implementing your own dispatch scheme with function objects or lambdas.

<sup>*</sup> in which case you would end up with a nearly classic C++ implementation of the [*Visitor Pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), a technique of implementing [*Double Dispatch*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch).

Comment: Ok, your answer is correct but as it happen, my problem is not properly modeled in my question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490493/c-function-overload-with-parent-and-child.