# Within a class in a namespace, can I exit **just** the class namespace?

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

This code does not compile:

```
class A;

void foo(A&) {
}

class A {
    void foo() {
        foo(*this); ///This does not compile
    }
};
```

Errors:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'A::foo(A&)'
         foo(*this);
                  ^
note: candidate is:
note: void A::foo()
```

This can be solved by calling `::foo(*this);`

---

However, let's consider the case we are in a namespace:

```
namespace bar {

    class A;

    void foo(A&) {
    }

    class A {
        void foo() {
            foo(*this); ///This does not compile
        }
    };

}
```

Is there any other way than calling explicitly `bar::foo(*this);`? I mean, is there any way to look up names in the next surrounding declarative region, i.e. the containing `bar` namespace?

The use case is similar to what seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29491078/2436175).

Comment: There is a way: rename one of `foo`s to something else, this will also save you some sleepless nights.

Comment: Your example is in no way related to this problem.  The example is a case of polymorphism where this is a name look-up issue.

Comment: @NathanOliver I corrected the pointer to the *accepted answer* to that question.

Comment: And still my comment is the same.  That solution is using polymorphism.

Comment: While namespaces are similar to directories in filesystems, there's no equivalent to `../`. The closest you get is `*this` versus `./`

Comment: There's no difference between `::foo` and `bar::foo`. `::foo` is just shorthand for something like `<global namespace>::foo`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I *removed* polymorphism from my question, if you want you can add it by adding a `class B` identical to `class A` and adding a prototype of `foo` function taking class B as argument. I removed to single out my current "problem", as if I get an answer here, I can apply to the case seen there. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MSalters Yep, I was thinking to the same example. And thanks for the edit!

Comment: @Dialecticus I think in my second example `bar::foo` and `::foo` are different: The first is defined, the second not.

Comment: In second example `::foo` is not defined for the same reason that some `<global namespace>::foo` would not be defined, which is that there is no function `foo` in global namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not within the method itself. However, you can do this in the .cpp file:

```
namespace bar {
  namespace {
    auto outerFoo = foo;
  }
  void A::foo() {
      outerFoo(*this);
  }
}
```

Note that the name `outerFoo` is a hidden implementation detail which  cannot cause name collisions (since it's in an anonymous namespace).

Comment: Great! I just regret not having access to C++11 `auto`, but in case I can get around it. Note: this becomes the accepted answer as it would work also when the `bar` namespace changes name.

Comment: Well in that case you either have to spell out the type or write `inline void outerFoo(A& a) { foo(a); }`.

Answer (score 4):

> I mean, is there any way to look up names in the next surrounding   declarative region, 
>   i.e. the containing `bar` namespace?

No.

You can sort of do it the other way around:

```
void foo() {
    using bar::foo;
    foo(*this); /// OK now
}
```

Comment: Why do you call it `the other way around`?

Comment: @Antonio Because it brings a name from an outer scope to the inner, narrower scope.